# How to change MLP structure to RNN structure in Pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch, recurrent-neural-network

I want to design an RNN Class structure that produces the same input and output as the MLP Class structure.

Actually, My MLP code is

```
class sample(nn.Module):
   def__init__(self):
      super(sample, self).init()
      self.linear = nn.Linear(1, 20)
   def forward(self, t, is_train = False, y = None):
       a = self.linear(t)
       return a
```

and I tried

```
class sample(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_dim, num_layer):
        super(sample, self).__init__()
        self.input_size = input_size
        self.hidden_dim = hidden_dim
        self.num_layer = num_layer
        self.linear = nn.rnn(1, 20,1, batch_size = false)
    def forward(self, t, is_train = False, y = None):
        a = self.rnn(t) 
        return a
```

but I think it is wrong, How should I modify the code?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```
class sample(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_dim, num_layer):
        super().__init__()
        self.rnn = nn.RNN(input_size, hidden_dim, num_layer)
    def forward(self, x):
        return self.rnn(x)
```

but it sounds like you can simply replace `sample` by `nn.RNN`
or `sample = nn.RNN` if you really can't change the code

[torch.nn.RNN](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.RNN.html)

BTW, https://discuss.pytorch.org/ might be a better place to ask this kind of questions...